# Cyrillic text with dompdf, print pdf scale error

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I need a help with this one. I use PHP and dompdf to create this invoice in Cyrillic:

[image: generated pdf]

On pdf everything is looking fine, but when I try to print it, I get it like:

[image: printed pdf]

and I get also one extra blank page added. Do you know how this can be fixed?

The example can be seen at: http://projects.stanislavstankov.com/php-pdf/pdfview.php

and sourse downloaded at: http://projects.stanislavstankov.com/php-pdf/php-pdf.rar

PHP code:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents("HTML Invoice Template.html");
$data = iconv('UTF-8//IGNORE','UTF-8//IGNORE', $data);
$data = preg_replace('/<body>/', "", $data);
$data = preg_replace('/<\/body>/', "", $data);
$data = preg_replace('/<html>/', "", $data);
$data = preg_replace('/<\/html>/', "", $data);


// inhibit DOMPDF's auto-loader
define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', false);

//include the DOMPDF config file (required)
require 'extensions/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

//if you get errors about missing classes please also add:
require_once('extensions/dompdf/include/autoload.inc.php');

//$data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
//$data = utf8_decode($data);
//$data = iconv('Windows-1251','UTF-8', $data);
//
//generate some PDFs!
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();     //if you use namespaces you may use new \DOMPDF()
$dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->load_html($data);
//$dompdf->set_paper(array(0,0,595,842));
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($log_id.".pdf", array("Attachment"=>0));

?>
```

Comment: I tried out the link and the file seems to load ok. Still having issues?

Comment: Seems there is problem with opening the fire directly in Firefox browser and printing it afterwards. IF files is download and printed normally - all is OK.

Comment: I was able to print (to paper) fine from Firefox, but not to PDF. The PDF printer (distiller) seems unable to locate the embedded font. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: The problem was not the embedded fonts, but the print of page